# auto hide the sidebar menu - wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://www.new.techmoney360.com is the website and it's made in wordpress.

If you visit the site you will see a big "showcase" type banner as the first item below the navigation bar.

To the right is optional other posts that a user can choose, or they can choose to hide it or show it.

By default, it's showing. I would like to make it hide on default and have the option to show it instead.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `/wp-content/themes/discussionwp/assets/js/modules.min.js`, find the first `mkd.windowWidth<769?`, where the `769` (actually `768`) means the maximum window width to auto hide the "showcase" on default. You can modify this number into a larger one (which is obviously larger than normal width of browser window, such as.. `9999`?) without editing other part of this encrypted JavaScript file.

Once you've done this, there will be an animation of hiding progress when you visit the site. If you want to get rid of this animation as well, you can add a property `style="left: 100%;"` in `<div class="mkd-post-block-part mkd-pb-four-non-featured">`, in Line 813 (as I can see) of the index file.

Comment: can I ask how on earth you figured that out? 
I have alot of things I want to get rid of on this site and they're extremely difficult to change. For example the stick scroll bar when you scroll down the page is driving me INSANE to try and remove. I'm deleted massive chunks of javascript that ever had `.mkd-page-header .mkd-sticky-header.header-appear` in any relation to it. I've used transform:none!important or even display:none!important in the select .css files and the sticky nav bar STILL apears.

Comment: Well I tried to look up  `mkd-hide-show-button` in all the related JS files (luckily there are only 2 appearances :P ) and checked them. For the question, if you want to remove the stick scroll bar (I hope I'm not misunderstanding your purpose), you can just remove the whole `<div class="mkd-sticky-header">` starting from Line 400?

Comment: line 400 from where? 
I can't figure out where you're seeing where this exactly is that's my issue lmfao.

Comment: To further clarify, how did you figure out all this out from just viewing a website? Whenever I try to figure out what someone's doing with a website I can only see the css (if I use inspect element from chome for example) :o

Comment: Just remove the code segment start with `<div class="mkd-sticky-header">`  and end with `</div>` before the next `</header>` of the index file. I wish that I speak clearly this time because I can't post any image in this comment part.

Comment: I checked this with using the inspect element from Chrome too. Just right click on the doubtful part and check the style of element with the tool. Click buttons or scroll the window and observe how the properties changing in the `Elements` window. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113554/discussion-between-robolisk-and-oprilzeng).